# Simple Addition (x += 50) vs loop to get result

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new to jQuery, but this is probably just a very basic code issue I think -- embarrassing I can't figure it out -- got it working through a silly work-around, but would really like to know what I'm missing??

I'm successfully taking a value from dynamically produced text.  Value is in percent, so I'm slicing off the % sign.  I'm trying to animate a bar on the screen to show the %, but need to add some size (50px) onto it in order to fill the div.  The code below does exactly what I need... but why on earth can I not just 'x += 50' or even 'x = x + 50'??  Either of those makes the bar go all the way across the screen.  I tried adding 'px', as I'm guessing I don't know the unit... but no joy.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.animate').each(function(){
    var x = $(this).text().slice(0,-1);
    for (a = 0; a < 50; a ++)  // Stewpid
        x ++;
    var posInfo = {'width': x};
    $(this).animate(posInfo, 1100);
 });
});
```

Anyone able to kick me in the head to see what I've screwed up?

Comment: don't use globals in `for` loop as variable  ....`for (var a = 0; a < 50; a ++)` ...can make a big difference. Also loop will run infinitely faster than what you want the animation to do. Not sure what you are expecting from this. Perhaps you want to look at `steps` option of `animate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.animate').each(function(){
        var x = parseInt($(this).text());
        x += 50;
        var posInfo = {'width': x};
        $(this).animate(posInfo, 1100);
    });
});
```

The problem was that `$(this).text()` is a string, even if you remove the `%` sign.

Now, in JS, `+` is both the add operator and the string concatenation, so the result would be a string, not an integer.

Instead, the `++` operator is an integer-only, so it casts your string to int before performing the arithmetic operation.

Just use `parseInt`, it will strip the `%` for you, and convert the result to int

Comment: And that's it!  Many thanks @JohnKiller - this was driving me crazy.  Your explanation was perfect.  Knew it had to be simple - just couldn't see it!